# How do I split an array based on the index of its values?

Tags: ruby

How do I split an Array with an indefinite entries:

```
["a","b","c","d","e",...]
```

Into even and odd arrays like:

```
["a","c","e",...]
```

and

```
["b","d","f",...]
```

Comment: Are you asking for even and odd splitting?

Comment: Are you asking whether the number of entries is even or odd? Because that varies.

Comment: Are you putting odd values in an array and even values in another one, or is this simply based on the index within the array?

Comment: I'm sorry. This is simply the index within the array.

Comment: You can't split an array with an infinite number of entries. Your machine will crash or never complete its operation.

Comment: Somebody edited it to say infinite. I didn't write that. It's just not clear in the beginning how many entries there are in this array.

Comment: Yes, I see that now. It's a bad edit and I'm surprised it was allowed. I'll clean it up so it's a bit more readable.

Comment: What. No. The title is wrong.

Comment: I'm looking through the revision list for the question, and it's not clear, even from the start, what you're asking. You can roll it back to any point, including your initial phrasing of the question, or you can delete it and try again. It's important you clearly specify what you want. The phrase "Numbers only represent the index of an entry." with the sample arrays doesn't clarify it enough. Try more complex arrays, like, what will happen for `['1','3','5','2','4','6']`?

Comment: You should consider my answer below as it's the only one that considers that you're splitting by index.

Comment: I don't understand? ['1','3','5','2','4','6'] would be ['1','2','3','4','5','6'] too. The title is correct now.

Comment: You could also look at mine below, which I believe is more clear to programmers than the other approaches.

Answer (score 10):

**Edited** based on comment:

```
arr = [:foo, :foo, :bar, :baz, :qux, :foo]

evens, odds = arr.partition.with_index{ |_, i| i.even? }

evens # [:foo, :bar, :qux]
odds # [:foo, :baz, :foo]
```

Comment: I am happy, with this.. So I deleted my answer.. :)

Comment: @ArupRakshit your solution was interesting too =) I wrote a general solution below that supports more than 2 partitions =)

Comment: Awesome! I love your use of [`Enumerator#with_index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index) here. I never would have thought of that.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit after clarification:**

You can do something like this:

```
odds = []
evens = []
array.each_with_index { |el, index| index % 2 == 0 ? evens << el : odds << el }
[odds, evens]
```

Comment: `[1,2,3,4,5].select { |el| el.even? } => [1,3,5] ` doesn't return what you think it does. You might want to fix that.

Comment: Check my new solution ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Rails or can `require 'active_support'` you can do this:

```
a.in_groups_of(2).transpose
```

Comment: What will this do if the array has an odd number of elements?

Comment: @Wayne `in_groups_of` will fill with a `nil` to make them even. `transpose` is happy with that.

Answer (score 0):

EDITED:
**general solution**

```
partitions_number = 2
['a','b','c','d','e'].group_by.with_index { |obj, i| i % partitions_number }.values
=> [["a", "c", "e"], ["b", "d"]]

['a','b','c','d','e'].group_by.with_index { |obj, i| i % 3 }.values
=> [["a", "d"], ["b", "e"], ["c"]]
```